# fabric8 as kubernates client : kill the pods which are idle for X seconds/minutes/hours

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, fabric8

i want to kill the pods which are idle for given duration (seconds/minutes/hours)

i'm using kubernates for deployment.

so i want to write the application (something like scheduler) for finding the pods which are in idle state for **xyz duration** *(seconds/minutes/hours)* and its associated details like labels which are tagged for the pod.

currently i'm using fabric8 as kubernates client.

so is there any api in fabric8 io for above requirement.?

if there is no such api in fabric8, then is there any alternative. please provide any links if exists

other than this, if there exists any best possible solution (for deleting the pods which are idle for given time of duration). please do help me out. thanks

Comment: What does "idle" mean?  How can the cluster manager tell?  (The horizontal pod autoscaler might fit your needs, but you need to connect it to some metric system.)

Comment: @DavidMaze      idle :-  pod is not doing anything, i mean pod has not received any request for 1minute/1hour or pod is not doing anything

Comment: I'm not sure if Kubernetes provides some way to individually control pods, usually controller resources take care of pods. You can use [HorizontalPodAutoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) like David mentioned, which scales automatically with respect to increasing/decreasing requests.

Comment: I think it can be done by writing a pod garbage collection operator which will watch all pods and delete those which have passed some time